# NSTextField on Dark NSVisualEffectView

Tags: cocoa

How do I fix the awful looking text on the NSOutlineView with a dark NSVisualEffectView sitting behind it?

[image: Jagged NSTextField on Dark NSVisualEffectView]

Bonus points for avoiding subclassing!

Comment: Are you setting the NSVisualEffectView's setWantsLayer: property to YES?

Comment: @blackirishman I have tried yes, nothing appeared to change.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with an NSTextField… I fixed it by subclassing the NSTextField and setting the CG context's setShouldSmoothFonts parameter to false. Like so:

```
class MyOutlineView: NSOutlineView {

override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    let context = NSGraphicsContext.current()?.cgContext
    context!.setShouldSmoothFonts(false)

    super.draw(dirtyRect)
}
```

}